# Switching active spellchecker language in Chrome using a key shortcut instead of context menu

Tags: mac, google-chrome, spell-check

I am looking for a way to quickly switch active language of spell checker in Chrome. The original way to do is to use right-click on the text field, choose Spell Checking[1] from the menu and then select appropriate language from the popup list. Seems easy and fast, but if you count in the menu lag and the time you have to spend browsing the menu it can get really annoying.

List most of the people I am just bouncing between two languages back and forth, so one or two keys to switch between those would be just great.

This is bothering me for longer period already. I did rather big research on this. There are even some partial threads about this on StackExchange, but I have to yet find a proper solution.

IIRC I get into a thread, when someone was claiming, that this is not possible (at least was) due to the way Chrome worked. Mainly, there was no build way and there was no API available to Extension to handle this.

Because of that I am getting a bit desperate already, to I am willing to accept any kind of solution, including any third party solutions, like those which simulate keyboards for you. This might be possible, since after the context menu shows you can navigate using the arrow keys.

I am not sure if thats really relevant (I guess so), but I am on ma Mac here. I assume that this problem also comes to play on other platforms, so I am posting here instead of any other Apple related site (like apple.stackexchange.com).

[1] - I am using localized version of the interface, so I am not sure how does this shows up while using english version.

Comment: I'm looking forsome extension too. I want to use chrome's built-in spellcheck because I'm czech and most of the 3rd party solution are only for a few "main" languages.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running out of options. As a last resort, I'd recommend using some software like AutoHotKey to automate clicks and keypresses. It may take you more time to learn and set up properly than it'll save you, however.

Here's a relavent thread on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332254/autohotkey-alternative-for-mac-os-x